# Bought an unlocked 5c how to activate without SIM card

Tags: iphone

I bought an unlocked 5c for my kid to use without data etc as an iPod to later use as phone when older but it wants a SIM card to activate the phone what do I do

Answer (score 0):

You need a SIM to activate. You can remove the SIM once this is complete. If you are really interested in WHY you will find similar questions.